# QGIS3 for Mac: KyngChaos vs Homebrew vs MacPorts?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, mac

How have been your experiences between the three ways of installing QGIS3 on a Mac? I've used KyngChaos (which right now I think is the QGIS official distribution for Mac) and the Homebrew's one.

Some of what I have learned throughout the process:

- If you want to keep the number of Python's installations on your computer low (if for example you are using Conda for Jupyter, GDAL for R, etc.), it's better to install everything using Homebrew. In my case, before installing everything using Homebrew, I ended up having official Python3 for KyngChaos QGIS3, Conda's Python3 for Jupyter, Homebrew's Python 3 & 2 for GDAL - GEOS - PROJ4. Now everything is Homebrew's Python2 & 3 (installing Jupyter using pip).
- The main issue with QGIS3 from Homebrew is that it takes a really long time to compile and install (about 40 minutes), which makes it a little annoying to wait all that time when you upgrade your packages.

I still haven't installed QGIS3 using MacPorts, so I'm wondering how it is compared with the other two options.

Comment: Did you try the one from Lutra? https://lutraconsulting.github.io/qgis-mac-packager/

Comment: no, I haven't. I didn't know it existed! it seems good because it is an all-in-one package, but if you want to reduce the number of Pythons redundant installations in your Mac it seems better to install QGIS from Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I use Macports 2.7.1 on Big Sur 11.6.4

```
sudo port install qgis3
```

This currently (As of Mar 2022) fetches QGIS version 3.22.2-Białowieża

It takes about an hour to build, compile and install but I have found its the only way I can get it to work reliably all the time. Am even able to have both SAGA & GRASS plugins co-exist peacefully.

At the same time just like OP said it reduces your python installs.

The only issue I have is that it currently lags behind the official version.

Answer (score -1):

On Mac OS 10.13.6 macports 2.6.2 I tried out the macports install with:

```
sudo port install qgis3
```

after I had tried

```
sudo port install qgis
```

which failed. I then learned that qgis3 would be the better version.
Unfortunately after the installation which took quite a few minutes there was no manual and no command line

```
which qgis3
which qgis
man qqis
man qgis3
```

all failed.

I Downloaded the dmg file from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html which is currently the only version I could get working.

on my ubuntu machine 18.04 LTS a simple

```
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

installed so that

```
 which qgis
 man qgis
```

and

```
 qgis
```

worked. The version installed was 2.18.17

Comment: please be patient - the third attempt of the  install is still running ...